# How to make sharp corners on a line in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, line-art, outline

I am making a logo with Illustrator.

I made an outline with the default stroke - no fill black stroke. But, the corners have a square end cap.

How do I make the end caps sharp so they are a point?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Adobe Illustrator Stroke Palette]

Go to Window -> Stroke

Modify the Cap, Corners, Limit, etc (ie, try a higher or lower number in Limit)

Additionally, make sure your shape is "closed" by completing the path just in case.

EDIT: Up your Limit to 30 or so.

Limit of 0:

[image]

Limit of 30:

[image]